# Custom pipe not recognized after creating an angular project from scratch, error NG8004

Tags: angular, typescript

I created an angular 16.1.0 application and a custom pipe but I got error messages when I compiled it . I'm going to mention the steps I did:

1. ng new exampleProject
2. ng new generate pipe power
3. I changed the content of app.component.html:

   ```
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    {{ 4 | power}}
   ```
4. I changed the content of power.pipe.ts:

   ```
   import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

   @Pipe({
     name: 'power'
   })

   export class PowerPipe implements PipeTransform {
     transform(value: number,exponent: number): number {
       return Math.pow(value,exponent);
     }
   }
   ```
5. ng s

Then I got the following error messages:

```
Error: src/app/app.component.html:2:8 - error NG8004: No pipe found with name 'power'.

2 {{ 4 | power}}
         ~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:5:16
    5   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "exampleProject",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^16.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
    },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.1.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~16.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.6.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.1.3"
    }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { PowerPipe } from './power.pipe';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PowerPipe
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
```

})
export class AppModule { }

What can I do to solve the NG8004 error?

Answer (score 0):

The name of the pipe is `power` but you are using `square` in the template.

Comment: Sorry. I made the correction in the post. I replaced square by power. Even though,, the error persists

Comment: Did you add pipe to module declarations?

Comment: Yes, it was automatically added by executing the command ng new generate pipe power

Comment: I already know what is happening. The exponent was missing. So I replaced  {{ 4 | power}} by {{ 4 | power : 2}} in app.component.html. Then the application started to work.